# Find an open set $V$ containing $(1, 1)$ such that $f|_V: V\to f(V)$ is bijective, where $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2\;\&\;f(x, y)=(xy, x-y)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

**Problem**: Find an open set $V$ containing $(1, 1)$ such that $f|_V: V\to f(V)$ is bijective, where $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by $f(x, y)=(xy, x-y)$.

**My Question**: Clearly $f(x_1, y_1)=f(x_2, y_2)\implies x_1y_1=x_2y_2\:\&\: x_1-y_1=x_2-y_2$, thus $x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2$. Hence both $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are points of intersection of the same line and circle. But Then how do I find the open set $V$? Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such open set! Indeed, $f(t,t)=(t^{2},0)$ and $f(-t,-t)=(t^{2},0)$. Any open set containing $(0,0)$ contains $(t,t)$ and $(-t,t)$ for some $t \neq 0$ so $f$ is not injective an any such open set.

Answer for the edited version:

We have $(x_1+y_1)^{2}=(x_1-y_1)^{2}+4x_1y_1=(x_2-y_2)^{2}+4x_2y_2=(x_2+y_2)^{2}$ which gives $x_1+y_1=\pm (x_2+y_2)$. If we choose any neighborhood of $(1,1)$ in which  the coordinates are both  positive then we get $x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2$ Since we also have $x_1-y_1=x_2-y_2$ we see that $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$ so  $f$ is injective in such a neighborhood.

Comment: I am so sorry-I meant the point $(1, 1)$ instead of $(0, 0)$.